# How can I escape from this mode inside git bash?

Tags: bash

[image]

The dollar sign disappears and the arrow sign pops up. Any idea why and how to handle this situation?

Comment: The backslash escapes the newline so that the command can be continued on the next line.  When you are finished with the command press enter to execute it.

Comment: Note: this is just plain old bash, being bash. "Git bash" is simply a port of bash to Windows, provided *with* Git because Git needs a POSIX-ish shell, and bash is one and the port to Windows works, so bundling it with Git (as "git-bash") gives Git one to provide. After that, though, it's mostly just plain old bash. The only things special are the adapters for Windows (where it becomes [tag:git-bash], a thing of its own that's neither Git nor bash).

Comment: The ">" character is from the `PS2` prompt. Bash has four prompts: `PS1` is for normal command entry and `PS2` is for continuation lines. [See more here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/193659/162084)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

backslash tells the terminal you want to continue typing our command on a new line.

hit enter to finish the command and execute

ctrl+c to get out of it without executing